# python basic programme exercise

Tags: python, list

I'm doing a course in udacity, and i got stuck in one exercise. I've changed my code a thousand times but I think that I'm not even close to the righ answer. The exercise is this:
define a procedure that takes in a string of numbers from 1-9 and
outputs a list with the following parameters:
Every number in the string should be inserted into the list.
If a number x in the string is less than or equal 
to the preceding number y, the number x should be inserted 
into a sublist. Continue adding the following numbers to the 
sublist until reaching a number z that
is greater than the number y. 
Then add this number z to the normal list and continue. So if the string is '543987' the out put should be [5,[4,3],9,[8,7]].

and my code is:

```
string = '543987'

def numbers_in_lists(string):
    result = []
    sublist = []
    counter = 0
    ref = 0
    for e in string:

      if e == string[0]:
        result.append(int(e))

      if int(e) < ref:
        sublist.append(int(e))

      else:
        result.append(sublist)
        sublist = []
        result.append(int(e))
        counter = counter + string.find(e)

      ref = int(string[counter])

    return result

print numbers_in_lists(string)
# [5, [], 5, [4, 3], 9]  which is not what i expected ([5,[4,3],9,[8,7]])
```

Is it too bad?? hope someone can help me.
Thanks!!

Comment: 575 fails. It returns [5,7,5] instead of [5,7,[5]] because the first check only checks if the character is equal to the first character, not if it's at the first character's position.

Comment: why the down votes? he clearly put some effort in, he posted the problem statement, and the code he tried(which seems like a reasonable attempt to me)

Comment: @JoranBeasley But he didn't say what the problem is with the code he posted. So what is he asking?

Comment: in his second sentence he posted he was not getting the expected output... ive edited his question to include what his code generates

Comment: @JoranBeasley thank you very much for the help and the corrections!! and i couldn't care less about that guy's downvote, so never mind

Answer (score 1):

there are only two options for each letter in the string

```
if int(letter) > last_letter:
    if sublist: # if we have any entries in our sublist 
       result.append(sublist) # append them before appending this letter
    sublist = [] # clear sublist
    result.append(int(letter)) # append our letter
else: # it must be lessthan or equal
    sublist.append(int(letter)) # so append to sublist
last_letter = int(letter) # update last_letter
```

then at the end before you return your result you want to do the same check

```
if sublist: result.append(sublist)
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    # YOUR CODE

    A = [] #create main list
    B = [] #create sublist
    length = len(string)
    i = 0
    biggest = 0 #initiate biggest number to compare with other number in the string
    while i < length:
        if int(string[i]) > biggest:
            biggest = int(string[i])
            A.append(biggest)
            B = [] #empty sublist to prepare for next round
        else: 
            if B not in A: #prevent adding another sublist B to A
                A.append(B)
            B.append(int(string[i]))

        i += 1    
    return A
```